# 2 Thunderbolt Displays to a MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro

Can I connect a second TB Display to my MacBook Air?  I currently have just one TB and would like to add a second

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is the model of your MacBook Air (see Apple menu>About This Mac)? Apple publishes technical specifications for every Mac model they produce and you get the information you need from there, **As an example**, the tech spec page for MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) states that it supports up to 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz **on an external display** (see https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753). If you have that model, It only supports one display.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your hardware, this search might help you understand if your hardware supports it.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&q=multiple%20displays%20air&product=&doctype=&currentPage=1&includeArchived=false&locale=en_US&src=globalnav_support&type=organic

Feel free to take away any of the & items if your Air is old enough the support KB is archived.

The current Air should be capable of most dual display setups: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211190

Comment: I found https://www.everymac.com/ to be much easier to navigate in such scenarios.